# Togglz Get Feature Name when status changes(enabled/disabled)

Tags: java, spring-boot, togglz

I need to retrieve the togglz feature name for which the status is changed. Is there any way to do that? I'm stuck with this for the past 1 day. Any help is highly appreciated. Please find my sample code below

```
    public enum MyFeatures implements Feature {

        @EnabledByDefault
        @Label("First Feature")
        FEATURE_ONE,

        @Label("Second Feature")
        FEATURE_TWO;
    }

    @Bean
    public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
        return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(MyFeatures.class);
    }
```

Whenever there is a change in the togglz status from togglz-console I need a way to get the name of the feature which got changed.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks tooglz doesn't have a feature to do it like you want. But it can be achieved using [CompositeStateRepository](https://www.togglz.org/apidocs/2.3.0.final/org/togglz/core/repository/composite/compositestaterepository) and implementing a new StateRepository to listen the changes.
PS: You should set the setter selction on CompositeStateRepository to 'ALL'.
I'm leaving here a dummy listener implementation:

```
public class ListenerStateRepository implements StateRepository {


    @Override
    public FeatureState getFeatureState(Feature feature) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFeatureState(FeatureState featureState) {
        log.info("{} was changed"); //you should handle the state change here
    }
}
```